# complete KVM / libvirt breakdown after OS upgrade (openSUSE)

Tags: opensuse, kvm, libvirt

I have upgraded two E-350 systems which have been running VMs (one of the systems only Linux VMs, the other one Windows VMs) to openSUSE 13.1 (i.e kernel 3.11.10, kvm-1.6.0, libvirt-1.1.2).

After a few seconds the VMs crash, in different ways:

1. (The already installed Linux and Windows VMs) Linux is doing magic, not in the positive sense though. I am not kidding: I have a **zombie** process which consumes a whole CPU core (at least according to `top`):

   ```
   3673 3 qemu 20 0 0 0 0 Z 100,1 0,000 2:07.08 [qemu-system-x86] <defunct>
   ```

   I need `kill -9` to get rid of it.
2. (The Linux / Windows DVD) The systems boots for a few seconds and then just stops. The `qemu` process is still around but it has less than 50 MiB resident memory and 0% CPU usage - but is shown as alive yet. Attaching with `strace` shows:

   ```
   futex(0x7f433536fac0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL
   ```

This happens both directly after the upgrade to openSUSE 13.1 and after installing the patches.

I have disabled AppArmor but that influenced the crash by a few seconds only.

Comment: Sounds related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/555981